# Manipulate the 3 Dimensions in Three.js from json object exported by Blender

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, blender

I was wondering if there is a way for the user to manipulate manually from my website a 3d object that was created by Blender and exported in json format by this [exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender).
I want the user to change the Length Width Height of the object.
For example i have this simple cube in json format

```
{
"metadata": {
    "generator": "io_three",
    "type": "Geometry",
    "vertices": 8,
    "faces": 6,
    "uvs": 0,
    "normals": 8,
    "version": 3
},
"uvs": [],
"name": "CubeGeometry",
"faces": [33,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,33,4,7,6,5,4,5,6,7,33,0,4,5,1,0,4,7,1,33,1,5,6,2,1,7,6,2,33,2,6,7,3,2,6,5,3,33,4,0,3,7,4,0,3,5],
"normals": [0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,-0.577349,-0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349,0.577349],
"vertices": [1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,0.999999,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1]
```

}

and i want the user to be able to change the 3 dimensions by typing numbers in a form, not mouse drug.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found it. If anyone wonders the solution is

```
var model = new THREE.Object3D();
model.add(object);
model.scale.set(x,y,z);
```

where object is your object :p